# Dropwizard test framework

Tags: rest, testing, jersey, dropwizard, jersey-test-framework

I am using dropwizard 0.9.3 core, test helpers etc... On a rest api test, I get 404 not found error.

javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found

```
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.convertToException(JerseyInvocation.java:1008)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:816)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$700(JerseyInvocation.java:92)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:700)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:696)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:420)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:316)
```

I have attached the code below:

```
public class ProfileResourceTest extends BaseTest {

private static ProfileService profileService = mock(ProfileService.class);
private static AuthenticatedSession authenticatedSession = mockAuthenticatedSession();
private static UserProfile userProfileFixture = mockUserProfileFixture();

@Context
private ContainerRequest request;

@ClassRule
public static final ResourceTestRule resources = ResourceTestRule.builder()
        .setTestContainerFactory(new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory())
        .addResource(ProfileResource.class)
        .build();

    @Test
public void test_resource_getProfile_success() throws ProfileNotFoundException {
    // setup
    doReturn(userProfileFixture).when(profileService).getUserProfileByUserId(any());
    // execute
    UserProfile userProfile = resources.getJerseyTest().target("/v1/user-profile/")
            .request()
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            .get(UserProfile.class);

    // verify
    verify(profileService).getUserProfileByUserId(any());

    // assertNotNull(userProfile);
}
```

Surprisingly on changing the dependency dropwizard-testing to 1.1.0, I receive another error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at io.dropwizard.testing.junit.ResourceTestRule$1.evaluate(ResourceTestRule.java:201)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```